# Android Phone Ip webcam app doesn't work with openCV in java

Tags: java, opencv

I downloaded Ip webcam app to stream a video directly to openCv in java,I tried to connect it using `this.videoCapture.open("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video");` As recommended in the image below

[image: here]

But I'm getting nothing yet it works with `this.videoCapture.open(0);` using my webcam .I also tried every thing on this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535645/ip-camera-with-opencv-in-java) changing the url to `http://192.168.43.1:8080/video.mjpg` and `http://192.168.43.1:8080/video.mjpeg` but no positive results.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by downloading Droid Cam for Pc and android instead of Ip Webcam.This helped me access my android phone camera easily instead of using url.I Opened the application and used

```
this.videoCapture.open(1);
```

Since it is recognized as webcam at index 1 in my case.